# QTcpSocket delay/buffering issue

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, buffering

I have two instances of my Qt application communicating via QTcpSockets

Some packets get stuck and are not received until the next packet is sent. This happens even if the next packet is sent several minutes after. So it seems there is some buffering which has no timeout.

I have tried QTcpSocket::flush() on the sender, without success. This happens with one Qt build (5.6.1) and not with another (5.4.2). Both are built with MinGW-w64 (Windows platform)

When I say the packet is not received, I mean that bytesAvailable() stays at zero (I have checked with a polling timer for debugging). readyRead() is never emitted as well.

For instance, I'm sending packet A and packet B just after. Then, I send packet C two minutes later. The receiver gets a complete packet A, but no packet B, and the socket has no bytes available for reading. When packet C is sent, I receive packets B and C.

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: QtcpSocket::flush() will only flush the internal buffers on the sender's site, and not do anything with the TCP connection. Could it be you're accidently swallowing a packet in your receiver, reading it into a buffer but not processing it (and then dumping its content)?

Comment: No, I'm not loosing the packet, I'm receiving it much later, when the following packet is sent. For instance, I'm sending packet A and packet B at the same time. Then, I send packet C two minutes later. The receiver gets a complete packet A, but no packet B, and the socket has no bytes available for reading. When packet C is sent, I receive packets B and C.

Comment: what you are describing is very close to the behavior of [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) (especially if you are sending small chunks of data) , maybe disabling it in the sender using [`socket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketOption) can help, if it does not try using a sniffer like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to confirm that the packets are not arriving at the receiver side.